# Gitlab on CentOS 7 with Apache instead of Nginx giving a “503 Service Unavailable” message

Tags: apache-http-server, gitlab

I just tried to install GitLab to my root server.

But hen I access the webpage using Apache for a proxy, I get a “503 Service Unavailable” message.

Here is my Apache VirtualHost configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.example.at

  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/
  <Directory /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes Off

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.example.at/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

The full `gitlab.rb` configuration file [can be found here on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/c0FVCX3S).

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache VirtualHost configuration, both lines read `ProxyPassReverse`:

```
<Location />
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse http://git.example.at/
</Location>
```

I think it should be:

```
<Location />
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse http://git.example.at/
</Location>
```

Comment: now i get the Message "ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location."

Comment: Ok, that's because of the `/` in the `ProxyPass` line. Please remove it.